# What are the implications of setting historySize on sessionPageState mean

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

What are the implications of setting `historySize`on `sessionPageState`?

```
<sessionPageState historySize="number" />
```

I am reading this link of msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228249%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

But there is not enough information. I am storing my viewstate in session. Does this mean this is the amount of postback for which the session stores the information? Is ajax request also counted as one item in session page state? The default number it says is 9. What should I ideally keep my historySize as?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In browser you have back button. When you click on back button it shows previous page data. To store previous pages history you can set that number.

Obviously, setting the historySize to an enormous number can cause the memory usage (for those storing session information in memory) to balloon so you’ll have to try out different settings depending on your site usage and resources.

Get more information from here....
https://web.archive.org/web/20211020131036/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/011707-1.aspx
http://elegantsolution.wordpress.com/category/sessionpagestatepersister/